# Create an empty matrix with certain dimension

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to create an empty matrix with 80 rows and 26 columns with the following code

```
a <- as.matrix(NA, nrow = 80, ncol = 26)
```

But this returns only a 1 x 1 empty matrix. I feel like an idiot because this should be so easy, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a single `NA` to a matrix.  That's why you get 1x1 matrix.  Correct syntax would be:

```
matrix(NA, nrow = 80, ncol = 26)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array(dim = c(nrow, ncol))`, e.g.

```
array(dim = c(80, 26))
```

which returns a 80x26 matrix with `NA`s.